# Where is API key for LinkedIn application

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

The [official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq) says:

> Click on the My Apps link in the top navigation menu to manage your
>   LinkedIn applications.
>
> From here, you can create a new application if you don't already have
>   one, or view the details of your existing applications.  You will find
>   your API Key value listed in the section named "OAuth Keys".

But the application pages has been probably changed without updating documentation because there is no "OAuth Keys" section at all.

Anybody knows where the API key can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I came across that too. It's actually called "Client ID", not "API key". Look under your App profile in the *Authentication* section

Comment: hey.. please answer this question if you can... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909797/how-to-invite-friends-using-linkedin-sdk-in-ios-app